# Ansible: Lineinfile with items in front of the other in same line

Tags: ansible, ansible-template

I want to know if it's possible to insert two or more items in the same line with module lineinfile or other modules.
Like that example:

```
- name: Insert content in the File
  lineinfile: 
    dest: /tmp/file.txt
    line: 'Groups = {{ item }}'
    create: yes
  with_items: 
    - "{{ group_ad }}"

group_ad:
  - LINUX
  - DBA
```

In the file stay that after executing the playbook:

```
Groups = LINUX

Groups = DBA
```

But I want to stay like below:

```
Groups = LINUX, DBA
```

Who I make that?

Answer (score 0):

You're iterating over the list, but you want to add the list. So it's easier to use join here

```
- name: Insert content in the File
  lineinfile: 
    dest: /tmp/file.txt
    line: 'Groups = {{ group_ad | join(', ') }}'
    create: yes
```

Comment: Use this `{{ group_ad|join(', ') }}`

Comment: @VladimirBotka thanks, your answer gave me the solution

Comment: sorry, yes - your right. was somewhere else.